# c++ thread running time

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance

I want to know whether I can calculate the running time for each thread.
I implement a multithread program in C++ using pthread.
As we know, each thread will compete the CPU. 
Can I use clock() function to calculate the actual number of CPU clocks each thread consumes?

my program looks like:

```
Class Thread ()
{
Start();
Run();
Computing();
};
```

Start() is to start multiple threads. Then each thread will run Computing function to do something. My question is how I can calculate the running time of each thread for Computing function

Comment: do you need to do this measurement all the time in the program and use the measured number? Or is this for debugging purposes?

if its for debugging, many tools exist to help you out. Let us know what platform you are coding for and what IDE you use and we might be able to help :-)

Comment: Right. If the reason you are asking is that you would like to find out what to change so as to minimize the overall execution time, then there are good answers to be found on SO.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot use `clock`. Processor could switch to another thread between `Start` and `Computing` calls so you will calculate the time of several threads. You need to use tick counter local for one thread.

Comment: Do you mean clock will include the running time for all threads? If so what I want is to use tick counter local for each thread. Could you pls give more explanations for tick counter?

Comment: Yes about `clock`. But thread local counters is a platform specific feature, what platform do you use?

Comment: Sorry, can't consult about apple.

Answer (score 3):

according to [clock_gettime(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime):

> Sufficiently recent versions of GNU libc and the Linux kernel support the following clocks:
>   CLOCK_REALTIME
>   System-wide realtime clock. Setting this clock requires appropriate privileges.
>
> CLOCK_MONOTONIC
>   Clock that cannot be set and represents monotonic time since some unspecified starting point.
>
> CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID
>   High-resolution per-process timer from the CPU.
>
> CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID
>   Thread-specific CPU-time clock.

so you may have *CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID* a try.

Answer (score 2):

What platform are you using?  If you are using Linux and are on kernel > 2.6.26 you can use the `RUSAGE_THREAD` flag to `getrusage`:

```
struct rusage usage
getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, &usage);
```

within `struct rusage`, you'll find `ru_utime` and `ru_stime` which tracks user time and system time respectively.  Call this once at the beginning and once after and you can get the delta.